# Puppet master log not created in configured location

Tags: puppet

Below is my puppet master puppet.conf file

```
[main]
logdir=/var/log/puppet
vardir=/var/lib/puppet
ssldir=/var/lib/puppet/ssl
rundir=/var/run/puppet
factpath=$vardir/lib/facter
certname = puppet
dns_alt_names = puppet

[master]
# These are needed when the puppetmaster is run by passenger
# and can safely be removed if webrick is used.
ssl_client_header = SSL_CLIENT_S_DN
ssl_client_verify_header = SSL_CLIENT_VERIFY
```

Though I've specified logdir in configuration to be `/var/log/puppet`, puppet master logs are generated in `/var/log/syslog`

Any solution?

Comment: "puppet config print | grep log" this link can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10450118/how-to-log-puppet-agent-and-master

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customise master log destination by editing :

- `/etc/default/puppet` (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS)
- **Edit** : `/etc/init.d/puppet` (Ubuntu 14.04 LTS)

Add the following to `DAEMON_OPTS` :

```
DAEMON_OPTS="--logdest=/var/log/puppet/master.log"
```

Comment: (see also: https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-2997)

Comment: @KrisFR There is no file `/etc/default/puppet`. Does it need to be created?

Comment: What is your Linux flavour ?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Comment: @deepdive In that case edit file `/etc/init.d/puppet`

Answer (score 0):

Should be simple to set the logging in your syslog daemon. The config I use is a below. Make sure to restart ryslog after you make changes.

**/etc/rsyslog.d/40-puppet.conf**

```
# PUPPETHEADER: This file is owned by Puppet.

if $programname == 'puppet-agent' then -/var/log/puppet/puppet.log
& ~

if $programname == 'puppet-master' then -/var/log/puppet/puppetmaster.log
& ~
```